# Error while importing excel data using xlsx library

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xls, xlsx

I'm trying to import excel data into my angular app using this library:

[xlsx](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx)

But when I downloaded the project and tried to run locally,when uploading the excel file I'm getting this error:

`Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to construct 'Worker': Script at 'file:///E:/Experiments/js-xls-master/xlsworker2.js' cannot be accessed from origin 'null'.`
Has anyone faced similar kind of issues or have used this library request you to share the thoughts for the above problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot run a WebWorker from a `file://` URL

A simple workaround is to run a local HTTP server in your project directory and access the site from the http URL

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

Your site will be available at http://0.0.0.0:8000